# JSOUP select all text following a closing tag until a specified tag

Tags: html, parsing, text, extract, jsoup

I have this html amongst a lot of table rows in a table:

```
.........
<tr class="greycellodd" align="right">
<td align="left">
<input type="checkbox" name="cashInvestment" value="100468057"/>
</td>
<td align="left">Cardcash 
</td>
<td class="nobr">26 Aug 10</td>
<td class="nobr"> 1.00 
</td>
<td class="nobr"> 1.00 
</td>
<td align="right">£</td>
<td class="nobr">0.00 </td>
<td class="nobr">0.00 </td>
<td class="nobr">
<span class="changeupsmall">1.00 </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="greycellodd">
<td align="right"/>
<td class="nobr" colspan="8">VISA</td>
</tr>
<tr class="greycelleven" align="right">
<td align="left">
<input type="checkbox" name="cashInvestment" value="100480214"/>
</td>
<td align="left">Santander
</td>
<td class="nobr">24 Sep 11</td>
<td class="nobr"> 1.00 
.......
```

I need to extract everything between each checkbox tag

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cashInvestment" ../>
```

Example

Elemtent 1:

```
Cardcash 
26 Aug 10
1.00 
1.00 
£
0.00
0.00
1.00
VISA
```

Element 2:

```
Santander
24 Sep 11
1.00 
.......
```

I have tried:

```
 Elements Inve = mainFirst.select("input ~ *" );
```

and

```
 Elements Inve = doc.select("input"); // gives me nothing as there is no text to the input tag (it has no child).
```

I also need to get the value of the checkbox, which I know how to do, but would be nice to do at the same time if possible:

```
Elements mainTables = doc.select("table.maintable");
for (Element subTable : mainTables){    
  Elements borrowInve = subTable.select("input[type=checkbox][name=cashInvestment]" );
  String attr = test.attr("value");
}
```

Thanks

Edit: resolved by checking the size :

```
    Elements td = tableRows.get(i).select("td");

            Elements cash = tableRows.get(i).getElementsByAttributeValue("name", attrValue); // check if checkbox is present
            int theSize = cash.size();

            if(theSize ==1){ // this row is not a comment 

                String checkbox = "";
                Element cbox = td.select("input[type=checkbox]" ).first();
                checkbox = cbox.attr("value");
             else if (theSize ==0){ // this row contains a comment
                                  .............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done anything in JSOUP, but having a quick look at the docs, maybe something along the lines of:

```
Elements Inve = doc.select(".maintable tr td:not(:has(input))");
```

Although it'd probably be easier if you could add a class to the elements you want to target.

Comment: Not quite there yet. So your code gives me a element per line of text basically an element per tr which does not have a checkbox ie: 1: Cardcash 2: 26 Aug 10 etc etc it does not detect when a checkbox is found which should trigger each new element

Comment: Well, if you know there's a checkbox for every `tr` you could do something like (remember, I've never done JSOUP): `Elements trElements = doc.select(".maintable tr");` and then in a `for (Element trElement : trElements)` loop you would do a select on the current row with a similar code to what I wrote, but narrowing it to the current tr, plus a second select looking for the checkbox value.

Comment: I figured this out in the end, marked it as answered as you pointed me in the right direction (see edited question)